# Android Tutorial - Adding Action Bar, duplicate class?

Tags: android

I'm trying to create the [Action Bar](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/index.html) by following the Android Studio tutorial.  I am familiar with VBA, C++, and Python, but this is the first time I've ventured into an App, which uses java, xml, etc. in one. I say that because I think I've misplaced (or misnamed) something in my code, as when I try to run this, I get the error `error: duplicate class: com.example.batman.myfirstapp.MyActivity`.

I don't understand how it's a duplicate, I only have one "MyActivity.java", so am thinking that I can't do more than one `public class MyActivity extends ...` per .java file?

Here's what I have (please let me know if I need to include other code):

MyActivity.java

```
package com.example.batman.myfirstapp;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.support.v7.app.*;

public class MyActivity extends ActionBarActivity{
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu items for use in the action bar
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_activity_actions, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle presses on the action bar items
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_search:
//              openSearch();
                return true;
            case R.id.action_settings:
//              openSettings();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
}

public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = ".com.batman.myfirstapp.MESSAGE";

    /**
     * Called when the user clicks the Send button
     */
    public void sendMessage(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
        EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
        String message = editText.getText().toString();
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message);

//         getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        // If your minSdkVersion is 11 or higher, instead use:
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

main_activity_actions.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:myfirstapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <!-- Search, should appear as action button -->
    <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
          android:title="@string/action_search"
          myfirstapp:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
    <!-- Settings, should always be in the overflow -->
    <item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
          android:title="@string/action_settings"
          myfirstapp:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

Again, I'm not sure what other files (strings.xml, DisplayMessageActivity.java, etc.) would be helpful to debug the above, so let me know what else I can include.

Thank you for any advice/help!

Comment: *I can't do more than one public class MyActivity extends ... per .java file?* You got it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're intuition is correct! You can only have one MyActivity class in your file, here's what it might look like:

```
public class MyActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = ".com.batman.myfirstapp.MESSAGE";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_activity_actions, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_search:
                return true;
            case R.id.action_settings:
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    private void sendMessage(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
        EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
        String message = editText.getText().toString();
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Comment: Duh! Thanks, and I appreciate the example too! I'll get my head around all this yet! (Thanks everyone else too!)

Answer (score 1):

Your assumption is correct. In your .java file you have two classes named `MyActivity`. You can only have one.